# CSS style box-vertical is not working in Mozilla Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I need to limit the text in the div

```
<div class="blog">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 nopadding">
        <img src="assets/experience-in-vizag.png">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 blog-content">
        <h3 class="capitalize">A Day In Vizag</h3>
        <p>As Vizag is located on the hilltop it’ll take nearly one hour to reach there. Now, if you’re new to Vizag and do not know Telugu, it’s best to go with the 1 day Vizag tourist package by AP Tourism.Vizag also has sundry hills and beaches to provide. </p>
        <div class="col-xs-8 col-lg-9 col-sm-8 col-md-9 author-details-row">
            <p class="author-details">
                Arun Kumar
                <span class="date">November 28, 2017</span>
            </p>
         </div> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is the CSS that I have used. If I remove `-moz-box-orient: vertical;` CSS rule it is working fine in Chrome

```
`blog-content p {
   font-size:14px;
   overflow: hidden;
   display: -moz-box;
   display: -webkit-box;
   display: box;
   line-clamp: 7;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 7;
   -moz-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   box-orient: vertical;
   line-height: 19px; 
   color: #666666; 
   padding-right:14px;
}`
```

[image: In Mozilla]
[image: In Chrome]